# How can i return interactive map?

Tags: python, numpy, web2py, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

I have this code for a map using a `netcdf` file of **European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts**.

```py
def interactive_map():
    import netCDF4 as nc
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

    #original name -> _grib2netcdf-webmars-public-svc-green-007-6fe5cac1a363ec1525f54343b6cc9fd8-b5oXS9.nc
    fn = '7.nc'
    ds = nc.Dataset(fn)

    #variables
    #longitude, latitude, time, pm1
    lons = ds.variables['longitude'][:]
    lats = ds.variables['latitude'][:]
    time = ds.variables['time'][:]
    pm = ds.variables['pm1'][:]

    mp = Basemap(projection = 'merc',
                 llcrnrlon = 97.085310,
                 llcrnrlat = 2.044212,
                 urcrnrlon = 106.896219,
                 urcrnrlat = 7.403567,
                 resolution = 'i')

    lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    x, y = mp(lon, lat)

    cscheme = mp.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(pm[0,:,:]), cmap = 'turbo')
    mp.drawcoastlines()
    mp.drawstates()
    mp.drawcountries()

    cbar = mp.colorbar(cscheme, location = 'right')
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig('map.png')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnQzv.png

What i want is add the map to a view of web2py, i know it saves an image and i can render the image, but *it's possible to show in an interactive map?*

This is what i have to show the map in a view:

```html
<!--index.html-->
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<img src="{{=URL('static','images/map.png')}}" width="500" height="600">
```

Answer (score 1):

My package ncplot (https://ncplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will automatically create interactive plots for NetCDF files. You just need to do the following:

```
from ncplot import ncplot
ncplot(fn)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't see the countries and states lines: https://i.imgur.com/Tekja2G.png

Comment: Coastlines will be added to an upcoming release. Under the hood it uses hvplot. Code samples here should work with your data: https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Geographic_Data.html

Comment: Nice tool @RobertWilson , never knew such a thing exists! I have used "ncview" for some time, but in some aspect the latter is harder to use (zoom in and out of map, for instance can be bad)... Nevertheless, could not see any way how to change the colorlimits for example. Is there possibility or a will to such feature?

Comment: Thanks @msi_gerva. The package is fairly new, and one week old on pypi. So plenty of things to add to it. Colorlimits and scales are on my to-do list. In the long-run I hope it can fully replace ncview, which is beginning to play very badly with modern 4K screens. Full screen browser viewing is much better.

Comment: Thanks @RobertWilson for the fast reply, hope you have time and opportunity to add those required features quick! BTW, any chance you can fasten the initialization of the application or is this my side? In my case (Linux Mint, Python2) it takes about 1 minute to start from cold... "ncview" is much quicker, but it might be that it initializes fast as it does not produce any plot in the beginning. Just a recommendation, not criticizing.

Comment: Can you possibly share the dataset (url etc.)? That sounds slow. Though it might just be a data type that it needs some optimization for

Comment: @RobertWilson , tried again today and now is working much faster... Anyway, looking for the possibility to change colormaps and colorlimits... Also, in my case, I could not browse netCDF containing just time-depth station data as the program complained about not finding longitude data... I guess I should take this discussion to some other location :). Great work, nevertheless!

Comment: Could you possibly raise an issue with that? https://github.com/pmlmodelling/ncplot/issues. Sounds like a bug I need to fix.